# StackOverflowError when updating a List with mocks

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, stack-overflow

When trying to test my updateFoos method below, updating field `List<Foo> foos` using spring-data on mongo, it fails with a `StackOverflowError` with a List of mock of Foo. It works with real instances of Foo.

Spring stuffs' versions:

- spring-data-mongodb: 1.9.1
- spring-data-commons: 1.12.1
- spring-aop/beans/context/core/expression/tx: 4.5.2

Here's the update method:

```
public void updateFoos(String id, List<Foo> foos) {
  mongoOps.updateFirst(query(where(FIELD_ID).is(id)),
                       new Update().set(FIELD_FOOS, foos),
                       clazz);
}
```

Here's the test:

```
@Test
public void givenPersistedBar_whenUpdateFoos_thenUpdatesThem() {
  List<Foos> foos = Collections.nCopies(10, mock(Foo.class));

  barDao.updateFoos(ID, foos);
}
```

And here's the stacktrace

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.io.FilePermission.init(FilePermission.java:203)
    at java.io.FilePermission.<init>(FilePermission.java:277)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getPermission(FileURLConnection.java:225)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.getPermission(JarFileFactory.java:156)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.getCachedJarFile(JarFileFactory.java:126)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:81)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:152)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(ClassLoader.java:1331)
    at java.lang.Class.getResourceAsStream(Class.java:2221)
    at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.inspectClass(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:101)
    at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:87)
    at org.springframework.core.PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.java:65)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.buildPreferredConstructor(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:109)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.<init>(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.<init>(BasicPersistentEntity.java:93)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity.<init>(BasicMongoPersistentEntity.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(MongoMappingContext.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(MongoMappingContext.java:39)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:299)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:489)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:446)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:689)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:314)
...
```

Comment: When you provide a mock object to any method, you should define the behaviour for that mock on various method invocations.

Comment: How are you running it when it works vs not working?  From the stack trace it's an AccessController error, so when you run it for real, is it in a Tomcat or other container that has the correct privileges? 

When you run the tests,  can I assume you are doing some sort of mvn build with tests?  In that case,  it's being run under the user account  (you)  and the mongo doesn't like that for some reason.

Comment: The test pass when, instead of providing a list of mocks of Foo, I create a bunch of Foo doing new Foo(), put them in a list and provide that list to my method.

Comment: Could you provide us the complete stacktrace (the snippet you gave us seems too short for a StackOverflowError, and there is nothing in it that looks like your methods).

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff, I could be it would be useless since the last 3 lines I currently pasted in are repeated X times until it breaks. There's nothing in the stack using my stuff...

Comment: @Jeep87c So you have a probably infinite recursion of the three springframework method calls. How is the code entering that recursion (bottom of your stacktrace)?

Answer (score 2):

Spring Data MongoDB analyses the entities you want to store in the database.
For this, it looks at properties of the class to store using reflection.

The mocks most likely have properties that form a cycle. 
Most likely something like a reference to the information how mocking should behave that also has a reference to the mocks.
Thus you get an infinite cycle.

If you want to know what the exact properties involved are, just put a breakpoint at the lines mentioned in the stack trace and debug away.

To fix it just don't use mocks. 
I'm not really sure why one would use mocks to test a repository.
And if you don't want to test the repository, but some code using the repository mock the repository.

Comment: I since refactored my test to create real instance of my DTO instead of mocking it for the Repository/DAO tests. But we were still curious to understand why it was failing with a mock.